# Chromedriver selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am working on a python project using selenium.

I get the following error and would like some help please

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
> from unknown error: unexpected command response
> (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)

My chrome is version 103, and so is my chrome driver.

Here is the code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

player = input("Which player: ").lower()
PATH = "/Users/makfadel/Desktop/Desktop-items/chromedriver 2"
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

s = Service(PATH)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
browser.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2022_per_game.html")
search = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/div/div/input[2]")
search.send_keys(player)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='players']/div[1]/div[1]/strong/a")))
    element.click()
    name = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='meta']/div[2]/h1/span")))
    print()
    print(name.text)
    print()
    szn = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[1]/div/p[1]/strong"))
    )
    games = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/p[1]"))
    )
    ppgame = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/p[1]"))
    )
    rebounds = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/p[1]"))
    )
    assists = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[2]/div[4]/p[1]"))
    )
    fg = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[3]/div[1]/p[1]"))
    )
    fg3 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/p[1]"))
    )
    ft = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='info']/div[4]/div[3]/div[3]/p[1]"))
    )
    print(f"Season: {szn}")
    print(f"Games played: {games.text}")
    print(f"Points per game: {ppgame.text}")
    print(f"Rebounds per game: {rebounds.text}")
    print(f"Assists per game: {assists.text}")
    print(f"Field goal percentage: {fg.text}%")
    print(f"Field goal from 3 percentage: {fg3.text}%")
    print(f"Free throw percentage: {ft.text}%")
except Exception:
    print(f"No player named {player}")
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

There has been an issue with **chrome driver 103 version**

Please find below the bug ids for the same,

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4121&q=label%3AMerge-Request-103

Check it on GitHub Selenium Issue - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10799

Solution

1. For now, until this issue is fixed try to **"Downgrade Chrome Browser To v102"** and **"Download Selenium Chrome Driver 102"** and try to run your script, as this issue is happening in **103** version.
2. Upgrade the chromedriver to v104

sample code snippet -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


// 1
option = Options()
option.binary_location='/Applications/Google Chrome Beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Beta'

// 2
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(version='104.0.5112.20').install()), options=option)
```

code reference - https://www.globalnerdy.com/2022/06/30/fix-the-chromedriver-103-bug-with-chromedriver-104/

Comment: this is turning to be a massive pain, brew pip is supposed to work all of this mix up for you but in the end we have to install it manually & still tweak it and in my case non work 102,103,104