# Loop though page with Selenium after login

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium to login to a site, after that I nevaigate to the page I need to scrape without problem. This is the start of my code

```
month_list = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] 

options = Options()

login = "https://www.example.com/signin?" 

options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(login)
[...]
```

After that I'm trying to loop through the page I need to scrape like this:

```
for m in month_list:
    url = f"https://www.example.com/data/{m}"
    driver.get(url)  
    
    page_source = driver.page_source
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
```

but I'm gettin this Error:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 54>()
     55 url = f"https://www.example.com/data/{m}"
     57 # print(url)
---> 58 driver.get(url)    
     59 page_source = driver.page_source
     61 soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")

File virt\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:447, in WebDriver.get(self, url)
    443 def get(self, url: str) -> None:
    444     """
    445     Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    446     """
--> 447     self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})

File virt\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:435, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    433 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    434 if response:
--> 435     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    436     response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    437         response.get('value', None))
    438     return response

File virt\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py:247, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    245         alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    246     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from unknown error: unexpected command response
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: which chrome Version you use?

Comment: Right now I'm working with the 103.0.5060 version, but in the future I'd also need to run the script in a different computer that could be another version

Comment: checks [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72942868/chromedriver-selenium-python) post it's maybe helpful.